# How to sum across multiple rows for multiple fields

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

Can anyone please advise on how to go about writing a SQL query to include the sum for multiple fields across multiple rows by group. I'm using the below query, but it keeps saying that the fields "in the select line are invalid because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

```
    Select ClaimId,InternalICN,BilledAmt, 
           Sum(PayAmt) as TotPayAmt,Sum(COBAmt) as TotCOBAmt,Sum(PrePayAmt) as  
           TotPrePayAmt 
    from CAIDEnc.IntEncTracking.EncounterList
    where BypassFlag = 0 and
     BypassReason = 0
    group by ClaimId, InternalICN
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: the only field that is problematic is BilledAmt.   What should this be?

Comment: Thanks, Sparky. I realized that BilledAmt should include an aggregate function or it needs to be included in the Group by clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you really want, you have two options:

**OPTION #1: Remove the `BilledAmt` from the `SELECT`**

```
Select ClaimId,InternalICN, 
           Sum(PayAmt) as TotPayAmt,Sum(COBAmt) as TotCOBAmt,Sum(PrePayAmt) as  
           TotPrePayAmt 
    from CAIDEnc.IntEncTracking.EncounterList
    where BypassFlag = 0 and
     BypassReason = 0
    group by ClaimId, InternalICN
```

or

**OPTION #2: Include the `BilledAmt` in the `GROUP BY`**

```
Select ClaimId,InternalICN,BilledAmt, 
           Sum(PayAmt) as TotPayAmt,Sum(COBAmt) as TotCOBAmt,Sum(PrePayAmt) as  
           TotPrePayAmt 
    from CAIDEnc.IntEncTracking.EncounterList
    where BypassFlag = 0 and
     BypassReason = 0
    group by ClaimId, InternalICN,BilledAmt
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. So no field can be included in a Select statement like this, unless it is preceeded with an aggregate function, or in the Group By clause?

Answer (score 1):

BilledAmt is not in the group by clause. You must put it there, or aggregate it with a sum, average or other function.

Answer (score 1):

BilledAmt is not in a aggregate query.  When you use group by you can only select aggregates or any field in the group by clause/

Comment: To clarify the reason why you cannot select BilledAmt is because when you group by the aggregates then there may be multiple values of BilledAmt within each group.